# Arithmetic progression formula

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

To find out the sum of arithmetic progression it has been given 
**S=n(a+l)/2**
And this formula has been derived in this manner
$$
S=a+(a+d)+(a+2d)+.........+(l-2d)+(l-d)+l
$$
And by reversing
$$
S=l+(l-d)+(l-2d)+........+(a+2d)+(a+d)+a
$$
On adding both we get
$$
2S=(a+l)+(a+l)+(a+l)+..........\text{ up to $n$ terms}
$$
$$
2S=n(a+l)
$$
$$
S=n(a+l)/2
$$
My question is that why in deriving this formula reversing of the sum takes place(that is)
$$
S=l+(l-d)+(l-2d)+........+(a+2d)+(a+d)+a
$$
Why not any other method?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can also prove the formula by induction, but the method you mentioned is very elegant and easy to understand. Why should we despense with such a beautiful method ?

Comment: Why not this method, the simplest one method?

Comment: Yes simple but reason behind doing this